# Undefined Symbol when Using XGBoost in C++

Tags: c++, xcode, xgboost

I want to include the `XGBoost` library in my `C++` project. Here are the steps which I have followed:

1. Download from `GitHub` by using git.
2. Compile `XGBoost` files using make -j4
3. In XCode, I add the XGBoost path into path search: [image: search-paths]
4. In my project, when I used to include, the `XGBoost` file can be found.
   However, when I execute my code, here is the error message: [image]

It saying that undefined symbol with function name in c_api.h

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?
If I want to compile these files in `Linux`, which command I should include in order to link the `XGBoost` library. Thank you so much for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

Did you set the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH?

If you want to compile on linux. Saying you did the following in your home:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost
cd xgboost
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make -j4
```

you include path is:

```
-I ~/xgboost/include/xgboost
```

the library will libxgboost.so will be present in ~/xgboost/lib
In order to link with this library you must add:

```
-L ~/xgboost/lib -lxgboost
```

Since It is a shared lib (.so) you have to modify your LD_LIBRARY_PATH and export it.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/xgboost/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

ps: an other solution if you don't want to modify  your LD_LIBRARY_PATH is to add

```
-Wl,-rpath=~/xgboost/lib
```

Comment: Xcode will probably reset `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`. It is not listed under https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/itcaec37c2a6

Answer (score 0):

Select project in navigator, under build settings,

- Set "Other linker flags" (`OTHER_LDFLAGS`) to the equivalent of `"-L<path> -<flag>"`. For example, for `{fmt}`,  it would be  `-L/usr/local/Cellar/fmt/7.0.1/lib -lfmt`

  Find it out using `pkg-config --libs <libname>`.
- If the lib file(s) is not under path, set "Library search paths" (LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS ) to the parent directory of the library.

https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/itcaec37c2a6